# iMX6 secured copy scp command fail

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, embedded

I am running embedded Linux on and iMX6 board. I would like to be able to put a file into my system with command 'scp'. I have Ubuntu running in a virtual machine in a desktop that has said files. Both are connected via a D-link Ethernet switch. I double check the ip address of my embedded system, and ping it to make sure the connection functions correctly. Everything works fine up to here.

So I then use the command with the '-v' option and get the following:

---

```
username@username-VirtualBox:~$ scp -v /home/username/Desktop/text.txt root@10.6.18.77:/
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 10.6.18.77, user root, command scp -v -t /
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips 1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.6.18.77 [10.6.18.77] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 10.6.18.77:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Yj5SwSWphjZW17IMFmDyP9DGzyUqhop9EiDhNUoX3P4
debug1: Host '10.6.18.77' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Authentication succeeded (none).
Authenticated to 10.6.18.77 ([10.6.18.77]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Connection to 10.6.18.77 closed by remote host.
Transferred: sent 1552, received 1200 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 16864144.6, received 13039287.0 debug1: Exit status -1
lost connection
```

---

It seems that the connection is being established, but for whatever reason the iMX6 is just dropping the connection. I am at a complete loss for how to troubleshoot it from here

Comment: According to the debug trace, you're authenticating and starting a session. But the session terminates immediately. This implies there's a problem starting the scp utility on the remote system. Is the scp program installed on the embedded system? If the embedded system has logs in /var/log, you could check there for messages from sshd.

Comment: SSH is running                                                                                         root@colibri-imx6:/# ps -ef | grep ssh
root       600   522  0 16:46 ttymxc2  00:00:00 grep ssh

Comment: Sorry, not used to this forum. I tried to put that in a separate line, and it just posted my reply. The above output from from the host machine. I see a few different log files in /var/log on my host machine. Which one should I be looking at?

Comment: So the iMX6 is able to function just fine as the client. I can have it pull or push files from my virtual machine. But as a host it's still dropping the connection. The ssh auth.log file on the iMX6 do not appear in their usual spots (/var/log/ appears to be the typical location). Is there a way of tracing where the log file might be? I even tried 'find -name auth.log' on the whole file system and came up with nothing.

Comment: sshd logs through the syslog service. You need to figure out what if any syslog service is running on the embedded system and see how it's configured to find out where it's writing log data. Look for a process with "syslog" in the name, or any files in /etc with "syslog" in their names.  Also: I suggested that you make sure the _scp_ utility is installed on the embedded system.